# Logging rotation using logrotate and timing

Tags: logs, timestamps, logrotate

I have just set up a fairly extensive logging and logrotation operation on a system, to hopefully eliminate or at least minimize the risks of out-of-space errors (possible vulnerabilities?).

However, I have not been able to find a definite answer to this question in the manpages for the `logrotate` service

**How does the logrotate service determine the timestamp of the last logrotation for its daily,weekly or monthly option?**

The excerpt from `man logrotate` goes as follows:

```
weekly [weekday]
              Log  files  are  rotated  once  each  weekday, or if the date is advanced by at least 7 days since the last rotation
              (while ignoring the exact time).  The weekday interpretation is following:  0 means Sunday, 1 means Monday,  ...,  6
              means  Saturday; the special value 7 means each 7 days, irrespectively of weekday.  Defaults to 0 if the weekday ar‐
              gument is omitted.
```

Is the time of the last rotation simply checked constantly (using a cronjob) by looking at the last modification timestamp of the previous rotated log file ?

If so, if a user manages to somehow 'fool' the system and force it to de-synchronize its system time (often it is fairly easy to do, because it being a very rare attack vector it is rarely properly guarded ) , consequently having `logrotate` create rotated logs with a future timestamp, will that essentially disable `logrotate` frequency-based rotation?

---

For reference: The system in question - because of `tumblerd` (whether it was because of the system's configuration, or an actual vulnerability I cannot say) , which is a type of a thumbnail manager from what I understand - was constantly adding entries in `syslog`, `user.log` and `messages` logs, reaching up to 100GB each before the system failure (first space-wise, followed by memory leaks and CPU load spikes ). Not only was this a problem in itself but it also made reading these 3 log files impossible, and the only solution I could think of on the spot was `echo "" > [filename]`  to clear them.

Answer (score 0):

Since `logrotate` is FOSS, you could just dowload the source and read it. On Ubuntu, the packaging system says:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ apt-cache show logrotate
Package: logrotate
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3.8.7-2ubuntu2.16.04.2
Priority: important
Section: admin
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Paul Martin <pm@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 113
Depends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-8), libc6 (>= 2.14), libpopt0 (>= 1.14), libselinux1 (>= 1.32), cron | anacron | cron-daemon, base-passwd (>= 2.0.3.4)
Suggests: mailx
Breaks: postgresql-common (<= 126)
Filename: pool/main/l/logrotate/logrotate_3.8.7-2ubuntu2.16.04.2_amd64.deb
Size: 37660
MD5sum: ae3cf957775ac5c9e72604ac80b71e24
SHA1: 78687a0db41fad8b25b9aaa0f9e9e01739cb6136
SHA256: 4089998610e24a849d0286f1a657a714e7f3fe249f82eef3896778054ea1753e
Homepage: https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/
Description-en: Log rotation utility
 The logrotate utility is designed to simplify the administration of
 log files on a system which generates a lot of log files.  Logrotate
 allows for the automatic rotation compression, removal and mailing of
 log files.  Logrotate can be set to handle a log file daily, weekly,
 monthly or when the log file gets to a certain size.  Normally, logrotate
 runs as a daily cron job.
Description-md5: bb73169bb75b2b8a2fda1453d214416d
Task: minimal
Supported: 5y

Package: logrotate
Priority: important
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 113
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Paul Martin <pm@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3.8.7-2ubuntu2
Depends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-8), libc6 (>= 2.14), libpopt0 (>= 1.14), libselinux1 (>= 1.32), cron | anacron | cron-daemon, base-passwd (>= 2.0.3.4)
Suggests: mailx
Breaks: postgresql-common (<= 126)
Filename: pool/main/l/logrotate/logrotate_3.8.7-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
Size: 37642
MD5sum: 858f35a2a3eec8dc07e9896f8a905981
SHA1: 18802ca05d004b4d70aa400920668f71af98b47e
SHA256: bc370a2003b18b1761adceed2fdf575122117cbf17edc6de377d64dc01623d6e
Description-en: Log rotation utility
 The logrotate utility is designed to simplify the administration of
Since `logrotate` is FOSS, you could just dowload the source and read it. On Ubuntu.  log files on a system which generates a lot of log files.  Logrotate
 allows for the automatic rotation compression, removal and mailing of
 log files.  Logrotate can be set to handle a log file daily, weekly,
 monthly or when the log file gets to a certain size.  Normally, logrotate
 runs as a daily cron job.
Description-md5: bb73169bb75b2b8a2fda1453d214416d
Homepage: https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 5y
Task: minimal
```

`Homepage: https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/` is a good starting place.

A good `logrotate` technique is to force the logging entity to close the current logfile and open a new one. This can be done through `signals`, or by (stopping the server;renaming the log file;starting the server).